# How to disable output of incremental file list in bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: bitbucket

I am using bitbucket pipelines with deployer.
In the build process all operations including "sending incremental file list" are shown.
The "sending incremental file list" is very long.

```
[staging] sending incremental file list
[staging] ./
[staging] .env
[staging] 
          1,473 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  
          1,473 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, ir-chk=3666/3668)
[staging] .gitignore
[staging] 
            673 100%  657.23kB/s    0:00:00  
            673 100%  657.23kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, ir-chk=3665/3668)
[staging] .htaccess
...
```

How to disable the output?
Could this be done in bitbucket settings or the bitbucket-pipelines.yml?